# How do i get a specific field from a Firestore Document in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I have a Firestore database of users that is like this:

[image: image of my firestore database]

And my rules are

```
    match /users/{userID} {
      match /public {
        allow read: if request.auth != null;
      }
      match /private/{document=**} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid == userID;
      }
    }
```

I'm struggling to request only the public data from their collection without fetching everything and encountering issues due to my rules. I'm using the Firebase Web Modular API, but the other version appears to have a .select function. However, I'm uncertain if that function would be compatible with my code.

The latest iteration of my code, which was generated by ChatGPT and isn't functioning, might seem nonsensical, but it's the closest I've come to a solution.

```js
export const getUserFromHashedUID = async (hashedUID, fields) => {
  const db = getFirestore();
  

  // const userDocRef = doc(collection(db, 'users', hashedUID), 'public');
  const userPublicCollectionRef = collection(db, 'users', hashedUID, 'public');
  const userDocRef = doc(userPublicCollectionRef, 'public');
  
  try {
    const docSnapshot = await getDoc(userDocRef);
    
    if (docSnapshot.exists()) {
      const publicData = fields.reduce((acc, field) => {
        acc[field] = docSnapshot.get(field);
        return acc;
      }, {});

      console.log(publicData);
    } else {
      console.log('No such document!');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error getting document:', error);
  }

};
```

Answer:
So as people pointed out its not a thing in the javascript SDK for some reason so im going to layout my database like

```json
users:{
  "1234567-private":{data:"data"},
  "1234567-public":{data:"data"},
  "9876543-private":{data:"data"},
  "9876543-public":{data:"data"},
}
```

because it has about the same efficiency as my original layout but will actully work with rules and such (with some fancy functions)

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a screenshot of your document/database structure in the Firestore web console, and of the code you use to access the (public) documents?

Comment: Alright i made the changes

Answer (score 1):

> I cant figure out how to just request the public data from there
> collection without getting everything

With the JS Client SDK it is not possible to get only a subset of the fields of a Document when fetching this Document. Security rules doesn’t change this behaviour.

One solution is to separate the data (I.e. private and public data) into two documents. Most efficient way is to use two different collections and assign the same (User) ID in the two collection for the data belonging to the same user.

A second solution is to use the [Firestore REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api): With the REST API you can use a [`DocumentMask`](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/DocumentMask) when fetching documents, which will "restrict a get operation on a document to a subset of its fields. ". Note, however, that a "hacker" could get the collection ID and fetch the documents without the Mask.

A third solution would be to use a Callable Cloud Function to access the Firestore documents. With a Cloud Function, you have full control on what you want to send back to the front-end, since you query the collection from within the Cloud Function and build the response in the Cloud Function. However, using a Cloud Function instead of a Client SDK has several drawbacks: see this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/should-i-query-my-firebase-database-directly-or-use-cloud-functions-fbb3cd14118c) for more details.